# Backbone: Delete won't bind?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to bind one of my backbone views so that, when a model is deleted, it's removed from a different view as well.

Seems pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to get the destroy method to bind to the view. I can bind to changes or new models, but deletes just aren't triggering. I remember vaguely reading something about an eccentricity with binding to delete, but I can't remember what it was or, more importantly, how to get around it.

Any ideas appreciated. In short, if anyone could offer an example of binding a delete call to Relevant code below:

### Source View

```
class BackboneDemo.Views.Tasks.ShowView

  # ...
  events:
    "click #mark_task_completed" : "markAsCompleted"
    "click #delete_task" : "destroy"


  destroy: () ->
    $('#contentArea').html('')
    $('#contentWrapper').css('display', 'none')
    @model.destroy()
    this.remove()
    return false
```

Edit: Still no joy. I've added more code below to show precisely where the issue is

### Model

```
class MyModel extends Backbone.Model
  # ...

  destroy: () ->
    console.log 'this is getting hit'
    super
```

### Target View

```
class TargetView extends Backbone.View
  # ...
  initialize:() ->
    _.bindAll(@, 'destroy', 'testmethod', 'render')
    @model.bind('destroy', @testmethod)

  testmethod: () ->
    console.log 'but this is not getting hit'
```

Comment: Where is the part where you bind to "remove" or "destroy" or "delete"?

Comment: It's in the target view code, in initialize. I've tried a variety of different lines in the hope of getting it to work, typically along the lines of @model.bind('remove', @test_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. In case anyone else comes across this issue, the problem is with the backbone-rails gem and how it's destroy() function works. There's a pending pull request that solves the issue, but the short of it is:

- Ensure the collection is passed through to the view
- Replace the default destroy() code with this:

  destroy: () ->
    getViewAndCollection = ((view) -> return -> {collection: @options.collection, view: @})(@)

  @model.destroy()
    success: (model, response) ->
      vars = getViewAndCollection()
      vars.collection.remove model
      vars.view.remove()
     error: (model, response) ->
       # Whatever you want for error functionality

You can see more at the pending pull request [here](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/pull/42/files)

Answer (score 0):

Whats about this:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove(), this)
    }

})
```

Comment: you probably don't want to call remove immediately, his example already shows 2 events bound to dom elements so he needs to call this.unbind() first and then this.remove().

Comment: Sure he can call every method he want

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added more information in the question above. Have tried this & many things like it but it's just not hitting that .remove() method. Any other ideas appreciated